# Error Bibtex "Use of \@year@ doesn't match its definition. \cite{}"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to start using Bibtex and I created a file 
d.bib:

```
@book{zz,
    title={Math ZZZ},
    author={Zzzz},
    year={2018},
    publisher={Litres}
}
```

and a simple example of a latex document: document.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}

start
\cite{zz}


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{d}
\end{document}
```

And after compiling (F8 and F5 in TexStudio) firstly everything was fine but later I have an error:

```
Use of \@year@ doesn't match its definition. \cite{zz}
```

And I googled a lot but I still don't know how to fix it. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `apacite` citation management package, you really should be using the `apacite` bibliography style as well. Conversely, if you must use the `alpha` bibliography style, it's a poor idea to be loading the `apacite` citation management package.

If you must use the `alpha` bib style, the `cite` package is (probably) more than enough.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{d.bib}
@book{zz,
    title={Math ZZZ},
    author={Zzzz},
    year={2018},
    publisher={Litres}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{document}
\cite{zz}
\bibliography{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful, I just had an idea to put the whole bibliography in the separate file like it is shown in this example youtube.com/watch?v=KS9GvK7cvmo .  Yes, if I include cite package the problem solves, so you have answered the question, thanks, but I don't understand why if I use the "apacite" style I have an error? ( there should be \bibliographystyle{apacite} in my code, as you noticed, sorry for my erratum)

Comment: and there is a way to put \begin{filecontents} in .sty file, and then input this file, but why there is an error with .bib file and how to do it so?

Comment: The `apacite` package and bib style file are designed to work together to create (a) a very specific type of authoryear-style citation call-outs and (b) a very specific formatting of the bibliographic entries. The files `apacite.sty` and `apacite.bst` are not supposed to be employed independently of each other. If you absolutely want to use the `apacite` style file, you should be using the `apacite` bib style as well. No exceptions.

Comment: @YuraHolubeu - You wrote, "why there is an error with .bib file and how to do it so". I'm afraid I don't understand what the issue is. Please clarify.